# Does Volley resize bitmaps?

Tags: android, image

For a recent project I started using [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) to do network requests and image loading. From the [Google IO Presentation](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) I seem to remember that Volley also does resizing of the bitmap. Spitting through the code I was trying to find where it is doing that.

I can see that there's logic in the ImageLoader and NetworkImageView to do resizing, but I never see it getting called with something else besides the default 0, 0 values.

Is anyone else aware of this or know of a fork/change to enable it? It looks like Volley is still young and there's not a lot of info on the web around it yet.